# Minimize under constraint on an interval

Tags: functions, conditional

I want find the minima of a (multivariable) function under a constraint which has to be fulfilled on a whole interval, let's say
$$
\nabla f (\underline x) = 0 \ \\ \ c(\underline x,s)\geq0\ \forall s\in [0,1].
$$
How do I implement such a condition into the `Minimize[{f[x1,x2,...,xn],c[x1,...,xn,s]>=0 ?},{x1,x2,...,xn}]` function?
Thanks in advance!

Edit: Ok, small mistake. I wanted a condition to be an inequality. If I just change that in the example proposed it is stated that this are not valid constraints:

```
f[x_, y_] := x^2 + y^2;
c[x_, y_, s_] = 2 x + 3 y + s;
NMinimize[{f[x, y], c[x, y, s] >= 0, 1 >= s >= 0}, {x, y}]
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a two dimensional example:

```
f[x_, y_] := x^2 + y^2;
c[x_, y_, s_] = 2 x + 3 y + s;
Minimize[{f[x, y], c[x, y, s] == 0, 1 >= s >= 0}, {x, y}]
```

This gives an answer that depends on the value of `s`, as is plausible. For your revised/edited problem:

```
Minimize[{f[x, y], c[x, y, s] >= 0, 1 >= s >= 0}, {x, y, s}]
```

Comment: But doesn't that just imply that `c[x,y,s]>=0` for just one special s and not for all? I wanted to enforce the constraint on the whole interval.

Answer (score 1):

This belongs to the class of Semi-Infinite Programming problems for which ad-hoc algorithms must be used. The most intuitive one (discretization) involves building a finite grid on the interval and imposing the constraint on the grid points only, thus obtaining a classical constrained optimization problem with n constraints. One solves a sequence of such discretized problems on increasingly fine grids until a suitable convergence criterion is satisfied.
You can check out the Wikipedia page for a list of references on this and other approaches:
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-infinite_programming